# MySQL "my.cnf" variables not updating after Ansible run

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

i'm creating a simple Ansible playbook for my Project where i'm installing MySQL on an Ubuntu VM.

As part of this setup i'm creating a custom my.cnf file in /etc/my.cnf and it looks like this after the *jinja2* template is done parsing it.

```
[client]
port   = 3306
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket           = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
log_error        = /var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log
pid-file         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
general_log      = on
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log

[mysqld]
bind-address     = 127.0.0.1
datadir          = /var/lib/mysql
pid-file         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
log_error        = /var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log
general_log      = on
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
socket           = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
user             = root
port             = 3306

# Disabling Symlinks is recommended for security purposes #
symbolic-links=0
```

Next, since i'm running Ubuntu i call

`service: name=mysql state=started enabled=yes`

And everything appears correct, but when i check my variables using

`mysqld --verbose --help` i find that the variables are wrong, for instance it says `general-log` is false and `symbolic-links` is TRUE even though i set it to 0 in this cnf file, same if i run `mysql show variables`

So, i've check that the file exists and is in `etc/my.cnf` and that it is loaded as `mysql --verbose --help` reports

`Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf`

Might it be a user permissions issue? I believe this my.cnf file belongs to the **root** user this might be the cause of the issue.

What i really need is some help debugging what might be going wrong as i'm relatively new to this kind of low level MySQL configuration.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're on Ubuntu, which automatically starts services after installation. Thus at the time you ask for it to be enabled and started, it has already been enabled and started. And of course if you run the playbook again while it's running, it's already started...

What you need to do is to set up a [handler](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change) that will *restart* the service. For instance:

```
$ cat roles/mysql/handlers/main.yml
---
- name: restart mysql
  service: name=mysql state=restarted
```

Then be sure to `notify: restart mysql` in any task that changes the configuration.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your reply, i already had the `notify` in place, sorry i didn't mention that, but yes it reloads MySQL and still the new configuration doesn't stick.

I've managed to make it work differently, by overriding the existing stock config at `etc/mysql/my.cnf` i don't know if this is a good practice or not, but i don't think it is. 

Perhaps my order of priorities is the other way around.

If `/etc/my.cnf` is the LOWEST priority then the stock `etc/mysql/my.cnf` would override it and that would explain my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work, it might apparently be related to the order in which these files are executed.

I was assuming that

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

This meant that `/etc/my.cnf` has priority over the others when in fact it appears to be the other way around, in this case it seems that `~/.my.cnf` would have the highest priority in case it existed.

Makes sense considering that `etc/my.cnf` is the most general and least specific file.

So what i did instead was to override the stock `my.cnf` file in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` with my own version. I wouldn't advise others to do the same as i believe you should keep the default and simply add your `my.cnf` to `/usr/etc/my.cnf` instead, in my case it's just for a Vagrant VM and that's why i don't worry all that much

I do believe this might be the issue if you believe i'm wrong please correct me.

A big thank you to @Michael Hampton for his help

**EDIT**

I might actually be wrong, i've attempted the `/usr/etc/my.cnf` method and it didn't work, which is a bit odd, i'm left not really understanding the logic behind `my.cnf` priorities or how you're supposed to override it without touching the stock one that comes with your installation.

In a pinch i can just re-write the stock one i guess, and you could force `mysqld` to use a specific `my.cnf` file through the `--defaults-file` argument but still i'd like to fully understand what is going on, so if anyone knows please add your thoughts.

Thanks